# Merge SQL Rows with identical ID after a UNION

Tags: sql, group-by, merge, union

Currently I have a table that I am forming with a UNION in order to calculate two different SUMS. Right now I have duplicate rows because one of the SUM's is null in each to perform the UNION.

This is what my table looks like now:
[Table Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SP8e.png)

I would like to simply combine the rows with identical SKU's. Below is what I have so far

```
DECLARE @dt1 AS DATETIME 
SET @dt1 = DATEADD(day, 0, '2021/5/1')
DECLARE @dt2 AS DATETIME 
SET @dt2 = DATEADD(day, -30, getDate())

(SELECT
  OD.[SKU] AS SKU,
  OD.[ProductName] AS Name,
  SUM(OD.[Qty]) AS #OrderedAllTime,
  null AS #OrderedInLast30Days,
 (W.Onhand - W.Committed) as Available FROM ORD_OrderDetail AS OD
  LEFT JOIN INV_OptionItemsKeys AS IK ON OD.SkuID = IK.SubItemID
  INNER JOIN ORD_order AS O ON OD.ordernumber = O.recordnumber
  JOIN INV_WarehouseItems W on OD.SkuID = W.ItemID WHERE O.Invoicedate IS NOT NULL
  AND O.void <> 1 
  AND O.OrderDate > @dt1 GROUP BY OD.[SKU], OD.[ProductName], IK.[key], W.ItemID, W.OnHand, W.Committed)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT
  OD.[SKU] AS SKU,
  OD.[ProductName] AS Name,
  null AS #OrderedAllTime,
  SUM(OD.[Qty]) AS #OrderedInLast30Days,
 (W.Onhand - W.Committed) as Available FROM ORD_OrderDetail AS OD
  LEFT JOIN INV_OptionItemsKeys AS IK ON OD.SkuID = IK.SubItemID
  INNER JOIN ORD_order AS O ON OD.ordernumber = O.recordnumber
  JOIN INV_WarehouseItems W on OD.SkuID = W.ItemID WHERE O.Invoicedate IS NOT NULL
  AND O.void <> 1 
  AND O.OrderDate > @dt2 GROUP BY OD.[SKU], OD.[ProductName], IK.[key], W.ItemID, W.OnHand, W.Committed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your friend is CASE statement.

```
SELECT
  OD.[SKU] AS SKU,
  OD.[ProductName] AS Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN O.OrderDate > @dt1 THEN OD.[Qty] ELSE 0 END) AS #OrderedAllTime,
  SUM(CASE WHEN O.OrderDate > @dt1 THEN 0 ELSE OD.[Qty]) END) AS #OrderedInLast30Days,
 (W.Onhand - W.Committed) as Available 
FROM ORD_OrderDetail AS OD
LEFT JOIN INV_OptionItemsKeys AS IK ON OD.SkuID = IK.SubItemID
INNER JOIN ORD_order AS O ON OD.ordernumber = O.recordnumber
JOIN INV_WarehouseItems W on OD.SkuID = W.ItemID 
WHERE O.Invoicedate IS NOT NULL
  AND O.void <> 1 
  AND O.OrderDate > @dt2 
GROUP BY OD.[SKU], OD.[ProductName], IK.[key], W.ItemID, W.OnHand, W.Committed)
```